# Requiring 'fetch' is returning an empty object in a React-Native app

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm currently working on my second react-native application. Previously I had simply required fetch like so:

```
var fetch = require('fetch');
```

I never installed it with npm, as it was already available by default.
I just started a new react-native project (after updating my react native cli) and now when I require fetch in the same fashion and try to call a fetch method my app crashes and I get an error that says

```
Object is not a function(evaluating 'fetch(API_URL, fetchObject)')
```

When I console out fetch with

```
console.log(fetch);
```

I get

```
{}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, it looks you don't event have to require fetch any more. It's just available globally.

Answer (score 0):

Try to include React/RCTNetwork subspec in native.